# Create Entity if it does not exist in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am trying to persist a Team object (entity) in the database using JPA, implemented by Hibernate.
One attribute of the Team is a Contact object. When I create a team object, and set the contact attribute, is there an annotation that I can use to say that when I persist a team, if the contact that I have provided to the team does not exist, go ahead and create/persist it?

```
//New Contact, that is NOT in the database yet
Contact c = new Contact();
c.setName("John Doe");

Team team = new Team();
team.setName("Ravens");
team.setContact(c);
//now make call to persist Team. Can the call to persist the team also persist the Contact?
```

Comment: How do you identify a contact? Don't you use auto-generated IDs?

Comment: Yes, the ID for a contact is auto-generated.

Comment: So, if you get the ID of the contact to set in the team, this contact is supposed to exist, otherwise you wouldn't have a contact ID.

Comment: I've updated my question to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: ManyToOne and OneToOne both have a cascade attribute, that you can set to PERSIST (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html). But I hope you realize that every time the above code would run, a new contact named "John Doe" would be created in the contact table.

Comment: I see, so the PERSIST would mean that the contact would be created each time, not only if it doesnt exist?

Comment: How could the contact exist, since it doesn't have an ID? You can't tell if a contact identified by an ID exists in a table without knowing its ID. That doesn't make much sense. Or maybe your question is: *suppose a user enter the name of a potential contact (ex: "John Doe"), then how to find a contact having this name in the database or create it if such a contact doesn't exist yet?* In that case, then that is pure business logic: you need a query to find the contact(s) with this name, and create it if the query doesn't return any.