# Check entity existence before calling merge

Tags: jpa

I have a simple abstract DAO, and I have created the following method:

```
protected T update(T entity) {
    return em.merge(entity);
}
```

where the entity is just any object annotated with @Entity in my application. Now... I want to throw an exception if you try to update a non existing object. I was going to perform a find before the merge, throwing an exception if the find operation returns null and merging if the entity exists. I was wandering if a better way exists for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution: You can do a check based on your primary key. An entity must (should?) have an `@Id` field:

```
@Entity
public class Entity implements EntityInterface{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Override
    public Long getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

}
```

with the interface

```
public interface EntityInterface{
    public Long getId();
}
```

By default, when you instantiate your entity, `id` is null and a value is assigned only after persisting in the database: The id will be generated by the method you defined via `@GeneratedValue`. Consequently, the following check should meet your requirement:

```
public abstract class AbstractService<T extends EntityInterface>{

    protected T update(T entity){

        // if by any chance you have to call this method on an entity with a null
        // primary key, it means that the entity has not been persisted in the
        // database yet
        if(entity.getId() == null){
            // or whatever
            return null;
        }

        return em.merge(entity);
    }

}
```

Hope this help

Source: [JB Nizet's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19895389/4906586) and personal code

Comment: Ok, but suppose you receive an update request, via REST or WSDL for example. This update request is relative to an Entity with id 50, but you have no row in your DB with this ID. What happens if you receive this request?

Comment: How the ID was generated? The failure point is obviously that it cannot handle arbitrary IDs. In the case of a REST interface, I assume that the client does not randomly pick up the ID and the ID, directly from this interface or from another, is fetched from the database.

Comment: OK you have convinced me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcomed. If it could help you, my methodology is "Database always tells the truth" so if any interface (REST, websocket, JSF...) has a data discrepancy, then the interface is wrongly configured